# jHipster - AngularJS route redirects to login even when authorities are removed from entity

Tags: angularjs, spring-security, angular-routing, jhipster

By default jHipster generated entities are accessable for ROLE_USER.
I would like to create entity which can be accessible even for unregistred/unauthorized users.

Let's call the entity: Company

What I've done is removal of ROLE_USER from authorities array in every state in company.js. I can enter the entity (companys) page by going to http://localhost:3000/#/companys (I can see it for a second) but angular automatically redirects to login view (http://localhost:3000/#/login).

I believe the behaviour of this routing is somewhere defined in jHipster however I cannot find it. Any hints for angular newbie? :)

**UPDATED**
Here is piece of config where I removed authorities:

```
angular.module('testApp')
.config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('company', {
            parent: 'entity',
            url: '/companys',
            data: {
                authorities: [],    <---- here I removed 'ROLE_USER'
                pageTitle: 'testApp.company.home.title'
            },
            views: {
                'content@': {
                    templateUrl: 'scripts/app/entities/company/companys.html',
                    controller: 'CompanyController'
                }
            },
            resolve: {
                translatePartialLoader: ['$translate', '$translatePartialLoader', function ($translate, $translatePartialLoader) {
                    $translatePartialLoader.addPart('company');
                    $translatePartialLoader.addPart('companyType');
                    $translatePartialLoader.addPart('global');
                    return $translate.refresh();
                }]
            }
        })
```

Comment: can you post the code for routing?

Comment: That's the catch, I am not 100% sure about the architecture of jHipster so I cannot discover where routing config is located. However I will update the question with piece of code where I specify authorities. Maybe this will help.

Comment: Problem solved: it was related to Spring Security context, angular controller was making calls to rest API which required authentication. I've disabled authentication for the rest and now routing is OK. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way at the `com.company.config.SecurityConfiguration` because this will permit all including the unregistered:

```
.disable()
.and()
.authorizeRequests()
.antMatchers("/company/**").permitAll() // <<<<< ADD THIS
```